# Redis 3.0 for .NET application

Tags: asp.net, redis, in-memory, distributed-cache

Can I use Redis 3.0 for my ASP.NET website?
Redis 3.0 as Distributed Cache on Linux and my website in ASP.NET 4.5, does this make any sense?

Comment: Care to give justification for the flag? This seems, rather, to be a pretty pointed and simple question ... the short answer is effectively one word: "Yes."

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can do this, in fact, in Windows Azure, [Microsoft recommends using Redis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn766201.aspx?ppud=4) as the distributing caching layer, and their turn-key Redis instances are running Redis 3.0 now.

You'll want to take a look at either [StackExchange.Redis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis/) or [ServiceStack.Redis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Redis/). Both are excellent .NET Redis libraries and available via NuGet. As pointed out in the comments below (thanks thepirat000), ServiceStack is a paid library above 6,000 Redis requests per hour, while the StackExchange library is released under the MIT license.

Comment: Be aware that ServiceStack is not free, it has a [Free Usage Quota](https://servicestack.net/download#free-quotas) which is unlocked with a license key.

Comment: Very good point, I forgot to mention that! Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure they run 3.0 now? I know they were on 2.8 and I didn't see any anouncement for upgrade.

Comment: What I know for sure is that we have multiple Azure Redis instances in US West and US East, and they all got bumped to 3.0 around August, IIRC. You are absolutely correct that Microsoft did not seem to give any prominent announcement or warning prior to (or after) this upgrade.